# How to handle the back key from ConnectionSettingstask called directly from a secondary tile

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7

i have a small wp7 application with just a main page. The main page has 4 buttons and calls the ConnectionSettingstask for wifi, bluetooth, airplanemode and cellular data setting. I have also managed to create secondary tiles for any of these buttons. The OnNavigateTo event handles the secondary tiles using a key passed from the tile

```
    Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    If (Me.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("_key")) Then
        Dim Key As String = String.Empty
        Key = Me.NavigationContext.QueryString("_key")
        Select Key
            Case "WiFi"
                Dim NewTask As New ConnectionSettingsTask
                NewTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi
                NewTask.Show()
                ....
        End Select
                NavigationContext.QueryString.Remove("_key")
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem ia that when the user uses the secondary tile to call a task, the application opens directly the connection settings page, but after that the back key, instead of opening the phone main menu, open the main page of my application

Answer (score 1):

If you navigated to A then navigated to B, you can remove A from the backstack, but only if A and B is in your application.

A solution is to close your application when it detects you're coming back from the settings page. The only way to do this is to throw an exception and don't catch it. (A bit of a hack) The problem is that this kind of solution is not marketplace friendly, an unhandled exception means your app won't pass certification.

Unfortunately there is no marketplace friendly solution for this problem.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. I decided to create this program as my first attempt with WP and i took the idea from Cennectivity Tiles (http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/apps/0a43a0ef-e04b-46d1-8c2f-1e615271dcc1) witch has this functionality, thats why i believe that there should be a marketplace friendly solution.

Comment: That's strange. Maybe they've asked for a technical exception, since this is a logical behavior, so maybe the Microsoft allowed this. As I know the official navigation system doesn't allow this.